# Facebook graph api website custom audience rules not created giving error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-custom-audience

I am trying to create website custom audience using Facebook graph API.
I have used the same rules data provided in their documentation, the audience created but the rule are not display there on Facebook Ads Manager side.
It is displaying following error while trying to edit the audience.

**This rule was created through API or third-party applications. It contains syntax that we currently don't support in our interface.**

Following is the rule parameter value

```
{
    "inclusions": {
    "operator": "or",
    "rules": [{
        "event_sources": [
           {
             "id": "<PIXEL_ID>",
             "type": "pixel"
           }
        ],
        "retention_seconds": 8400,
        "filter": {
            "operator": "and",
            "filters": [{
                "field": "url",
                "operator": "i_contains",
                "value": "shoes"
            }]
        }
    }]
  }
}
```

Following is the link of Facebook documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/website-custom-audiences#create-audiences

[image]

Comment: I am also facing this same issue. If it is resolved for you then kindly provide the resolution for the same.

Comment: Hello @Nikhil , It is still having the same issue, if I found solution will surely post it here.

Comment: Hello @Shailesh , Posted the solution below. It worked for me

Comment: Hello @Nikhil, Thanks for the solution. Will check it & mark your answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. Sharing in case others are facing the same issue.

Syntax which I was using earlier.

```
{
"inclusions": {
"operator": "or",
"rules": [{
    "event_sources": [
       {
         "id": "<PIXEL_ID>",
         "type": "pixel"
       }
    ],
    "retention_seconds": 8400,
    "filter": {
        "operator": "and",
        "filters": [{
            "field": "url",
            "operator": "i_contains",
            "value": "shoes"
        }]
    }
}]
```

}
}

Correct Syntax

```
{
    "inclusions": {
        "operator": "or",
        "rules": [
            {
                "event_sources": [
                    {
                        "type": "pixel",
                        "id": <PixelId>
                    }
                ],
                "retention_seconds": 15552000,
                "filter": {
                    "operator": "and",
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "operator": "or",
                            "filters": [
                                {
                                    "field": "url",
                                    "operator": "i_contains",
                                    "value": "shoes"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```